# Laravel Innerjoin Related Count filter

Tags: laravel

I have missions table and mission completes table which are related.

Mission table has limit column and any mission completed it creates a record in mission completes. I want to query missions which has limits. So when i query i must innerjoin completes table and count the related mission completes, if its equal or less than limit i want to show the record.

But i cant figure it out.

I tried below query;

```
         DB::table('missions')
        ->join('mission_completes as completed', 'missions.id', '=', 'completed.mission_id')
        ->selectRaw('completed.*, count(*) as completed_count')
        ->where('limit','<=','completed_count')
        ->where('active',1)
        ->groupBy('completed_count')
        ->get();
```

But it gives below error;

```
        SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'missionproject.completed.id' 
        isn't in GROUP BY
```

Comment: You need to add the id to the groupBy, because you can't have columns in select that are not part of the groupBy clause. But for me that groupBy does not make much sense

Comment: Yes but neither groupby nor not its not working.